# UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

As I'm trying to solve the code below, the error shown and notifying `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap` deprecated in iOS 6.

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode =UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size =[chatText bound]
    CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0f, 1000.0f)];lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
```

how do i fix this code? thanks in advance for your contribution.

Comment: Please, don't type your code into Stack Overflow. Copy and paste it from your actual project. That code is not real code - it would never compile, not in a million years. Show real code, not fake code.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for UILineBreakModeWordWrap? Did you read what it says to use instead?

Comment: If you hold down the option key, and click on  `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` in your code, you'll get a popup window that tells you what the replacement is.

Comment: @rmaddy ya, i did, like what matt suggested and its working fine now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way is to refer to the NSLineBreakMode.